# Should you still pass only the object id when using ActiveJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activejob

What are the pros and cons of doing the following in ActiveJob:

Option A:

```
# Controller
MyJob.perform_later(object.id)

# my_job.rb
def perform(object_id)
  object = Object.find(object_id)
  # do stuff
end
```

Option B:

```
# Controller
MyJob.perform_later(object)

# my_job.rb
def perform(object)
  # do stuff
end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ActiveJob` now [uses the new `Globalid` library](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid) behind the scenes to serialize/deserialize an ActiveRecord instance, therefore you can now pass an `ActiveRecord` object.

I personally prefer to keep passing the ID as it makes the code more interoperable with other components and it doesn't tie my code indefinitely to a specific `ActiveJob` behavior, but this is more a personal choice.

Comment: I prefer passing the ID as well, in my instance ActiveJob had an Error while trying to deserialize arguments because I have a 'UrlValidator' on the object that was being passed. Passing just the ID, like @Jacob Option A worked well for me.

Comment: @simone-carletti Can you explain what you mean by "it makes the code more interoperable with other components"?